# Understanding TZ(Time Zone) variable in Unix

Tags: shell, solaris, timezone

I was trying to find older dates using `TZ="GMT+NoOfHours" date`. To my surprise, it was absolutely working as expected when NoOfHours >= 0 to NoOfHours <=167(returning date older by 1-7 days). But, when NoOfHours went greater than 167 it returned current date. I'm curious to know the reason for this behavior rather than other possible solutions.

Current date

```
-bash-5.0$ TZ="GMT" date
Thu Mar  4 14:59:42 GMT 2021
```

NoOfHours = 144(24*6)

```
-bash-5.0$ TZ="GMT+144" date
Fri Feb 26 14:59:47 GMT 2021
```

NoOfHours = 168(24*7)

```
-bash-5.0$ TZ="GMT+168" date
Thu Mar  4 14:59:50 GMT 2021
```

And, this left me confused!

```
-bash-5.0$ TZ="GMT+167" date
Thu Feb 25 15:59:54 GMT 2021
```

Comment: Why the drive-by downvote? It's a reasonable question that seems to be on-topic

Comment: @roaima Always this undying hope that the down-voter would return to explain ... ;)

Comment: More an attempt at reassurance to a relatively new user that their question is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TZ` variable is defined [under POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) to range from -24 to +24:

> The hour shall be between zero and 24, and the minutes (and seconds)-if present-between zero and 59. The result of using values outside of this range is unspecified. If preceded by a '-', the timezone shall be east of the Prime Meridian; otherwise, it shall be west (which may be indicated by an optional preceding '+' ).

GNU and others have [extended this range](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) to ±167 hours:

> The hours part of the time fields can range from -167 through 167; this is an extension to POSIX.1, which allows only the range 0 through 24

Solaris 11.4 appears to be strictly POSIX in regard to its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37853/environ-7.html#REFMAN7environ-7), but GNU-like in regard to its implementation (or perhaps you are using the GNU `date` variant in your testing)

Comment: BTW: POSIX requires at least -25h < off < +26h since there is an overlap in the date limit. It may be that someone just selected the next larger unit  > than a day. This is because the offset des not only apply to GMT but to any valid timezone.

Comment: @schily it's an `hh[:mm[.ss]]` offset from UTC

Comment: Sorry, the name before the offset is the name to be used ad the offset is an inverse GMT offset. I was mistaken.