# Date and time zone offset not working correctly

Tags: solaris, date, timezone

I'm facing a strange behavior of date command when using time zone offset on Solaris.

```
>echo $TZ
MET
>date
Wed Mar 31 11:41:45 MEST 2021
>TZ=MET+24 date
Tue Mar 30 09:42:06 MET 2021
>TZ=MEST+24 date
Tue Mar 30 09:42:52 MEST 2021
```

Why date output is showing MEST when TZ is set to MET and how is TZ+24 is showing 26 hours offset instead of 24 in both timezones.

Comment: Related - [Understanding TZ(Time Zone) variable in Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/637603/100397)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you are looking to understand why this (simplified) is happening:

```
$ TZ=MET date; TZ=MET+0 date
Tue 01 Jun 2021 06:00:00 AM MEST
Tue 01 Jun 2021 04:00:00 AM MET
```

That is: there are two hours difference between `MET` and `MET+0`.

The simplest of ways to debug this issue is to add a `'+%z'` format. That will print the offset that date is using to print the result and could help to debug where is the problem.

```
$ TZ=MET date "+%c %z"; TZ=MET+0 date "+%c %z"
Wed 31 Mar 2021 06:11:16 PM MEST +0200
Wed 31 Mar 2021 04:11:16 PM MET +0000
```

That shows that date is printing the results at `-2` offset and at `+0` offset.

The question is then: **Why?**

Maybe because the first format of TZ is `std offset` (something similar to TAG-03 [POSIX reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tzset.html#tag_16_629_06)) in which the **TAG** of the standard zone is defined and an optional offset for such tag is given. If missing, the offset is assumed to be `+0`.

So, we are setting the `name` to MET and the offset to +0.

Proof:

```
$ TZ=MET date "+%c %z"; TZ=METX+7:30 date "+%c %z"
Wed 31 Mar 2021 06:19:00 PM MEST +0200
Wed 31 Mar 2021 08:49:00 AM METX -0730
```

The *TAG* is simple: it is the name that will be printed for the time zone.

The offset used for such tag is the one given: `-7:30` (no questions asked).

It should be clear for you that there is no such `METX` tag anywhere and furthermore that there is no such offset of 7:30 at that tag.

That explains why a `MET+24` printed a zone time with the tag `MET` and an offset of `+0` in yesterday (equivalent to `+24`, try `+12` if you wish).

## Correct TZ

We could test a TZ that *says* that standard time is 7 hours and that summer time is 9 hours: **MET-7MEST-9**. To test we need faketime (need to be compiled for Solaris) which prints:

```
$ # In January (no DST):
$ faketime "1/1/21 12:00" bash -c 'date -u; TZ=MET date "+%c %z"'; \
  faketime "1/1/21 12:00" bash -c 'TZ=MET-7MEST-9  date "+%c %z"'

Fri 01 Jan 2021 04:00:00 PM UTC
Fri 01 Jan 2021 05:00:00 PM MET +0100
Fri 01 Jan 2021 11:00:00 PM MET +0700

$ # In June (DST in effect)
$ faketime "6/1/21 12:00" bash -c 'date -u; TZ=MET date "+%c %z"'; \
  faketime "6/1/21 12:00" bash -c 'TZ=MET-7MEST-9  date "+%c %z"'

Tue 01 Jun 2021 04:00:00 PM UTC
Tue 01 Jun 2021 06:00:00 PM MEST +0200
Wed 02 Jun 2021 01:00:00 AM MEST +0900
```

That is just to confirm our analysis. The TZ value could be reduced to **MET-7MEST** as the default effect of the DST is to increase the time on 1 hour. And, as the real UTC offset of MET is +1, we can settle on saying that TZ should be: **MET-1MEST**. If the dst tag is missing (`MET-1`) the dst offset is not applied.

For your goal of setting time to **yesterday** (+24 hours), you should use:

```
TZ='MET+23MEST'
```

Questions?

Comment: Long live knowledge, everything is clear, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

MET alone apparently refers to Middle European Time (= UTC +1 hour), which transitioned to Daylight Saving Time version (UTC +2 hours) on last Sunday of March (March 28 this year), and the DST version is known as Middle European Summer Time. So effectively "MET" is interpreted as a shorthand for "MET-1MEST". The total UTC difference of 2 hours comes from 1 hour of timezone-based UTC offset and 1 hour of DST offset.

From that, I can also see that the base UTC time when you entered those commands was about 09:42 UTC.

But when you specify "MET+24", that is "some strange timezone that uses the identifier MET and converts to UTC so that (local time) + 24 h = UTC." For converting UTC to local time, that formula is applied in reverse, so "local time in MET+24 timezone" is UTC - 24 hours, or UTC time exactly one day in the past.

And since there is no DST rule for "MET+24", no DST correction gets applied.