# Setting time zone in a kindle bash file

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, busybox

I've recently jailbreaked my kindle to make it a clock that shows a certain image for each minute of the day. I used the instructions mentioned in this article

https://www.instructables.com/Literary-Clock-Made-From-E-reader/

The thing is to do this there is a scribt to make it work, in the script it shows this code for getting the timezone

```
#!/bin/bash
test -f /mnt/us/timelit/clockisticking || exit
MinuteOTheDay="$(env TZ=CEST date -R +"%H%M")";
```

The thing is, whenever I put in my time zone, which is GMT+4, it never shows the correct time.
Even if the time is set correctly on the kindle, it just keeps using its own time.

I tried

```
MinuteOTheDay="$(env TZ=GMT+4 date -R +"%H%M")";
```

and

```
MinuteOTheDay="$(env TZ=Asia/Muscat date -R +"%H%M")";
```

and

```
MinuteOTheDay="$(env TZ=GST date -R +"%H%M")";
```

and they didn't give the correct time,
is there a way around this, am I missing something? Is there a way to make the script take the time from the kindle time?

Comment: Could you show the output that you get and the output that you expected to get?  Is there a reason you're using the `-R` option with `date`? Could you try using `Etc/GMT-4`?

Comment: I don't see an output in the kindle as it executes it. It is supposed to take the hour and minute and look for a corresponding png image for that hour and minute and display it as the time. as for the -R I have no idea what is the reason. I didn't write the original code and I'm familiar with it

Comment: Why do you run `env`? Also why do you provide two formats to `date`? `date` alone raises error for me for two formats. Please update with the exact output you get if you run your command.

Comment: i'm not an excpert I using following the instructions given. Also I've dropped the env and used this line 
MinuteOTheDay="$(TZ=Asia/Muscat date  +'%H%M')"
it still shows time at GMT timezone which is 4 hours behind

Comment: add `MinuteOTheDay=$(expr \( $MinuteOTheDay + 400 \) % 2400)` in a second line (obviously kindle's `date` do not take care of `TZ`'s value)

Comment: I wonder if the Kindle uses `busybox` and its built-in `date` utility, which is not really made for date formatting tasks.  Do you know what OS (more specifically) and toolset you are actually working with here?

Comment: I have no idea, this is Kindle 3 from 2010

Comment: @Archmar Thank you, the second line fixed it <3

Comment: I have added the busybox tag. If I was wrong, please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There was something going wrong in the kindle, no matter how much I tried to solve it or change the timezone. but what worked is adding this line

```
MinuteOTheDay=$(expr \( $MinuteOTheDay + 400 \) % 2400)
```

as suggested by Archemar

So full solution is (start with)

```
#!/bin/bash
test -f /mnt/us/timelit/clockisticking || exit
MinuteOTheDay=$(date +%H%M)
MinuteOTheDay=$(expr \( $MinuteOTheDay + 400 \) % 2400)
```

Comment: I add full solution, I also edit question title as I think knidle (or at least busbox is a key point)

Answer (score -1):

Use GMT0, and consider the difference between that timezone relative to you, which is -4hrs:

```bsh
MinuteOTheDay="$(env TZ=GMT0-4 date -R +"%H%M")";
```

Based on this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642964/473564

Comment: Same issue, it shows 10.07 am when it is 14:07 PM :"(

Comment: Ok, I guess there is some issue with the clock because here it shows 14hrs, a workaround could be just adding the time difference as an offset, ej: `MinuteOTheDay="$(env TZ=GMT0+10 date -R +"%H%M")";`

Comment: It didn't I've tried as many as I can do. someone suggested this fix and it worked 
add MinuteOTheDay=$(expr \( $MinuteOTheDay + 400 \) % 2400) in a second line